# How to provide Sentinel value at the end of Structure Array

Tags: c, structure, sentinel

I've created a structure of 10 elements (11th for sentinel value) and a structure pointer, assigning address of first structure element to it.

```
struct student
{
    int roll_no;
};

struct student s[11];  
struct student *ptr = &s[0];    

s[10] = NULL;    // Sentinel value
while (*ptr != NULL )  // Sentinel Controlled Loop
{
    printf ("%d - ", ptr -> roll_no);

    ptr++;
}
```

How do I provide a sentinel value in the end of a structure array ?

EDIT : values in structure are changing dynamically i.e. i've created space for 10 structures but it might happen their will be only 5 elements present their at a moment.  and sentinel value at 6th position.
when user enters a new structure element, sentinel value shifts forward etc 
so i can not use a (int i < 10) condition to simply print all the values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sentinel must be of type `int` (or some other field within `struct student`), such as:

```
s[10].roll_no = -1;
```

Your `while` loop will be as follows:

```
while(ptr->roll_no != -1)
{
    ...
    ptr++;
}
```

Comment: Thnx for the solution.
Though just out of curiosity, could their be any other efficient way to achieve the same without taking up space for one extra structure ?

Comment: @BrainDead A singly linked list would be a better solution.