# How do I determine the number of elements in an array?

Tags: c

I just got some problems to determine the number of elements in one of my arrays.
I got for example following code:

```
typedef struct
{
    char b[100];
    int c;
}abc;

typedef struct
{
    char qwe[50];
    abc *poi;
}def;

abc xyz[] = {
    {"xyz", 10},
    {"ijk", 20},
    {"gdf", 30},
    {"hfg", 40}
};

abc uio[] = {
    {"cde", 50},
    {"ghi", 60},
    {"hbc", 70}
};

def mnb[] = {
    {"kio", xyz},
    {"mkl", uio}
};
```

I know that I can determin the number of elements in the array `mnb` like this:

```
int count_mnb = sizeof(mnb) / sizeof(mnb[0]);
```

But how do I determine the number of elements in `xyz`? I want to use `xyz` as part of the first element of `mnb` and not just replace `mnb` by `xzy`. Something like this:

```
int count_xyz = sizeof(*mnb[0].poi) / sizeof();
```

But I couldn't figure how to do this.

Comment: you can't since `poi` is no longer an array but a pointer

Comment: Or specifically *this* answer from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37545/918959

Comment: Or use a sentinel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720551/how-to-provide-sentinel-value-at-the-end-of-structure-array